# SSMS, Visual Studio, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Need Help please.
I have installed SSMS and Visual Studio.
I have 2 issues.

1. I am trying to learn SQL DBA and hence I installed SSMS only, I haven't installed SQL Server/Express.
   While opening up a new query on SSMS, it asks me to enter the server name which I am unable to find and neither I can find instance name anywhere in my computer.

I have tried everywhere cmd and configuration manager.

2. Same with visual studio, when I try to create database, it doesn't allow me to add new local db as it doesn't show up when I try to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is based on the client/server database system. SQL Server Management Studio is a *management client*, **so you need a SQL Server installation in order to use it**. You can install SQL Server Express for free which has a very similar feature-set to the paid editions (Standard and Enterprise Editions).

...in comparison to MS Access or SQLite which are a file-based database systems.

Visual Studio is an IDE which has some database tooling (SSDT: SQL Server Database Tools), while it can also be used for DBA tasks it is more appropriate for software development tasks using SQL Server than SSMS.

Comment: Thanks Dai. Much appreciated. :)